# reloadSlider is not a function

Tags: jquery, slider, reload, bxslider

I have a footer-content and it opens if user clicks on i.
In this footer-content, there is a slider. But if i click on i and footer is opened, the slider doesnt works.

Sorry for my bad english.

Here the JS-Codes.

```
  var footerSlider = $('.gallery_link_list_slide').bxSlider({
        minSlides: 6,
        maxSlides: 6,
        slideWidth: 200,
        slideMargin: 10,
        ticker: true,
        speed: 50000,
    });  

    $(".footer_up i").click(function(){
        $(".footer_content").slideToggle( "slow" );
        $('.footer_up i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
        footerSlider.reloadSlider();
    });
```

If i resize the window, the slider works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slider has reloaded on click i always. it means if on click plus slider reloaded and on click minus too.

Now i solved this problem.

```
$(".footer_up i").click(function(){
       if($(".footer_content").css('display') == 'block') {
            $(".footer_content").slideUp("slow");
            $(".footer_up i").removeClass("fa-minus");
            $(".footer_up i").addClass("fa-plus");
       }
       else {
            $(".footer_content").slideDown("slow");
            $(".footer_up i").removeClass("fa-plus");
            $(".footer_up i").addClass("fa-minus");

            var footerSlider = $('.gallery_link_list_slide').bxSlider({
                minSlides: 6,
                maxSlides: 6,
                slideWidth: 200,
                slideMargin: 10,
                ticker: true,
                speed: 50000,
                auto: true
            }); 
       }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the CSS has absolute positioning set to 0 as mentioned below for your footer, `absolute positioning` and `bottom: 0`